# How to load data asset into an R script when creating a job in Azure Machine Learning?

Tags: r, azure, command-line-interface, jobs

I'm currently using R to create a machine learning job in Azure Machine Learning using the CLIv2. I have a repo that I have loaded into AML with similar structure as below.

[image: directyory]

I'm currently struggling to understand loading data from my datastore, more specifically a registered data asset. Not sure how I reference that data asset within the r scripts optparse function.The specific path I'm trying to point to is a uri_file .

[image: data_asset]

YAML

```
command: >
Rscript r-source.R
--data_file ${{inputs.datafile}}  
code: src   # this is the code directory
  inputs:
    datafile: # this is a registered data asset
      type: uri_file
      path: azureml:versiontest@latest    <--- I think this is right
```

R script

```
library(optparse)

parser <- OptionParser()

parser <- add_option(
  parser,
  "--data_file",
  type = "character",
  action = "store",
  default = "" <-- not sure what goes here, or how to reference the data asset
)

args <- parse_args(parser)
```

Was able to run a job successfully by just adding the relative path when I click on the actual data asset. However, not sure how to pull the data from here or prove the data was loaded.

Answer (score 0):

`default` is simply the value you want to use if no parameter is passed to the script.  It can be whatever you want it to be.

See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/optparse/optparse.pdf

To see if you successfully got the data, read it and display in R, for example, if it's a csv file, use:

```
mydata<-read_csv(args$data_file)
head(data)
```

Comment: omg thank you Sheri for creating an account on my part, it is a pleasure!!! Any recommended reading or resources for creating an ML pipeline using R? I'm currently struggling and have more questions than answers. Such as can i download more than one set of data using a job? Are registered data assets / datastores recommended over a datastore that isn't registered when referencing inputs within a job?